# Bash increment variable individually but sed is globally replacing?

Tags: bash, shell

In the script below, I'm trying to replace the letter "T" on every line, with $n and then go to the next line and $n+10, however sed appears to be replacing all instances of "T" with the total number. What have I missed? Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash -x
n=10
i=0
 while [ $i != `wc -l < filename.txt` ]
 do 

 sed -ie "s/T/$n/" filename.txt ;
 n=$(($n+10))  # echo $n

  i=$(($i+1))
  done
```

Comment: For 2+10, do you want 12 or 210? Can you add example input/output?

Comment: You are calling `wc` for every loop iteration: call it once before the while loop and save the result in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Sed will process your whole file every time you call it.

You could get around this by passing an address to do the replacement, but that would be horribly inefficient compared to the following alternative:

```
awk '{ sub(/T/, 10 * NR); print }' filename.txt
```

This replaces the first occurrence of `/T/` on each line with the result of `10 * NR`, where `NR` is the line number. So the first T on the first line will be replaced by 10, first T on second line by 20, etc.

If you're happy that the command does what you want, you can overwrite the original file the standard way:

```
awk '{ sub(/T/, 10 * NR); print }' filename.txt > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Note that this single command replaces your *entire script*, not just the call to sed inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are processing the whole filename.txt on every loop iteration. So the last iteration is the one that sticks.
You would need to process one line at a time and then put together and output the complete file.

A better solution might be awk. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { n=10; }
/T/ {
    print n, $0;
    n=n+10;
}
```

with the input file

```
T one
T two
T three
```

You get

```
10 T one
20 T two
30 T three
```

on stdout.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash -x
n=10
i=1
ln=`wc -l < filename.txt`
while [ "$i" -le "$ln" ]
do
sed -ie "$i s/T/$n/" filename.txt ;
n=$(($n+10))  # echo $n
i=$(($i+1))
done
```

`sed -ie "$i s/T/$n/" filename.txt ;` - only replaces the $i line

ex:

```
cat filename.txt
T aaa
T bbb
T ccc
./a.sh
cat filename.txt
10 aaa
20 bbb
30 ccc
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, this is very inefficient compared to an approach that processes the file once in a single command.

Comment: i know, but he interested how do with `sed` (and how not globally replace).

Comment: If someone asked you how to chop vegetables with a spoon, wouldn't you suggest that they used a knife? :)

Comment: :D that's so bad comparison